# Elementor - Custom Query / Use case outside of Elementor

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, elementor

I'm attempting to call a hook 'elementor/query/dtk_custom_query' inside of the php of a widget I created. The reason for this is so that I can keep the same query my Elementor loop grid is using.

Here's what the query modifier looks like:

```
function dtk_custom_elementor_query_callback($query) {
    //get query options
    $options = esc_sql($_GET);
    $meta_query = ($query->get('meta-query')) || [];
    $page = 1;

    //escape if in editor
    if (array_key_exists('action',$options)) { return; }

    //set meta_query options
    foreach($options as $key => $value) {
        $real_key = $key;
        if ($key==='show') {
            $query->set('posts_per_page',intval($value));
        } else if ($key==='pagination') {
            $page = intval($value);
        } else {
            //check if it's a _min or _max
            if (strpos($key,'_max') || strpos($key,'_min')) {
                if (strpos($key,"_max")) {
                    $real_key = explode("_max",$key)[0];
                    $meta_query[] = [
                        'key' => $real_key,
                        'value' => $value,
                        'type' => 'DECIMAL',
                        'compare' => '<=',
                    ];
                } else if (strpos($key,"_min")) {
                    $real_key = explode("_min",$key)[0];
                    $meta_query[] = [
                        'key' => $real_key,
                        'value' => $value,
                        'type' => 'DECIMAL',
                        'compare' => '>=',
                    ];
                }

            //if not min or max, then it's an equal
            } else {
                $meta_query[] = [
                    'key' => $real_key,
                    'value' => array_map('addSpaces',explode(",",$value)),
                    'compare' => 'in',
                ];
            }
        }

        //allowed keys check, immediately kick user to home if an invalid key is used.
        if (!in_array($real_key,dtk_query_fields)) { header("Location: /"); }
    }

    //finish up query here
    $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
    $query->set('post_type',['inventory']);
    $query->set('paged',$page);
}
```

And here is what the code from my widget looks like:

```
        $query = new WP_Query();

        //PHP for query counts
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'inventory',
            'posts_per_page' => $show,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged' => $page,
        );

        
        $query->query($args);
        
        do_action( 'elementor/query/dtk_custom_query', $query);
```

For some reason, the only results the query is giving me are those of the arguments I specified in my args table. It's as if the meta-query does not work.

I've attempted to modify the query itself, and even attempted to create it into a filter with no luck.

Comment: I forgot to mention I have this in the modifier php file: 

add_action('elementor/query/dtk_custom_query','dtk_custom_elementor_query_callback')